# Shut off windows sound using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, audio

How can I shut off the windows sound from an ASP.NET page.

Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET web page I think it's clear !

Comment: A significant portion of the browser using population is completely opposed to web pages changing the behavior of their computer outside of the browser itself. Browsers have been coded accordingly...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to?

Comment: Also, what if I'm browsing your ASP.NET web page using Firefox on Mac OS X?  Or if I was a blind user and I was using a screen reader to read your web page aloud?  Or if I was browsing your web site on my iPhone?

Comment: This another thing, I'm trying to implent it just on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why on earth would a browser let you shut down the whole OS sound? Leave my sound alone!

Even if your on a desktop app, still, leave my sound alone!

Comment: @AZIRAR: This is equivalent to saying: "I want to build a telephone that is capable of giving painful electric shocks to the person I am talking to."  What could *possibly* make you think that (a) this is worth doing, and (b) that your users would want it?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing that would be through an unsecure plug-in or ActiveX control.

Also, doing so is just wrong in any case. Navigating to a web-page doesn't imply permission to change system-wide parameters.

Comment: So the user must activate the ActiveX control ?
How can I implement this ?

Comment: I don't think windows comes with any way to mute the whole system sound (or manipulate it). You might be able to talk to drivers directly, but...

Comment: Another option would be to implement a protocol handler for your own "mute://" protocol that would need to be installed locally (as stand-alone application and no browser plug-in). To mute the volume you could use the Endpoint Volume API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370839%28VS.85%29.aspx)